# SQL - How to get 'number of days since last active day' using day flags

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have a schedule which runs on just Mondays and Thursdays, this is represented in the form '1001000'.

It's easy enough to check if my schedule is running today with:

```
set datefirst 1

--select...
--where substring(dayflags, (select @@datefirst), 1) = '1'
```

But how can I get the number of days since the most recent active day?

For example:

Running on Monday should return 0
Running on Tuesday should return 1
Running on Wednesday should return 2
Running on Thursday should return 0
Running on Friday should return 1
Running on Saturday should return 2
Running on Sunday should return 3

Comment: Don't do fancy string manipulations for operations that should use a table.  Create a table for the day lookup rather than a string.

Comment: Is `'1001000'` supposed to be a bit-field held as a string??

Comment: it's not clear how 1001000 represents your schedule.

Comment: Apologies to clarify, 1001000 is the days of the week (the first 1 is the Monday, the second 1 is Thursday)

Comment: I should also add it's not possible for me to correct the (flawed) underlying architecture of this existing system, so this is just a case of questioning whether or not it's possible to achieve given the provided format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is really not good.

But if you cannot change the architechture you may use this query:

```
set datefirst 1

declare @dt date = getdate() + 1 - 1
    , @mask varchar(7) = '0010010'

select charindex ('1', reverse (left (@mask + @mask, datepart (dw, @dt) + 7) ) ) - 1
```